# Regular expressions python data extraction

Tags: python, regex, csv

How to use python regular expression to extract data from the below two string

```
TASK000123-Tomcat server hosted on tbu.test1 is down-P1 --In Progress

TASK000123-Tomcat server hosted on tbu.test1 is down-P1 --Completed
```

I need the following csv file from this:

> Format: TaskID,Priority,Status

```
TASK000123,P1,In Progress

TASK000123,P2,Completed
```

How can I do this? Thanks for helping me out

Answer (score 2):

This is one approach using a simple iteration.

**Ex:**

```
s = """TASK000123-Tomcat server hosted on tbu.test1 is down-P1 --In Progress
TASK000123-Tomcat server hosted on tbu.test1 is down-P1 --Completed"""

result = [["TaskID","Priority","Status"]]

for i in s.splitlines():
    val = i.split("-")                          #Split by '-'
    result.append([val[0], val[2], val[-1]])
print(result)
```

**Output:**

```
[['TaskID', 'Priority', 'Status'],
 ['TASK000123', 'P1 ', 'In Progress'],
 ['TASK000123', 'P1 ', 'Completed']]
```

Comment: Too fast for me I was about to post the same thing :)

Comment: Thanks you so much. Can you tell me how to put the result in a csv file?

Answer (score 2):

Here in an option using `re.findall`:

```
input = "TASK000123-Tomcat server hosted on tbu.test1 is down-P1 --In Progress\nTASK000123-Tomcat server hosted on tbu.test1 is down-P1 --Completed"
results = re.findall(r"(TASK\d+).*?-(P\d+) --(.*)(?=\n|$)", input)
print(results)

[('TASK000123', 'P1', 'In Progress'), ('TASK000123', 'P1', 'Completed')]
```

Note that `DOT ALL` mode should not be necessary here, because we never need `.*` to match across newlines.  Also, the above seems to work without using `MULTILINE` mode as well.

Comment: Nice, still wished I knew regex like some of you do

Comment: @Jaba To really get proficient with regex, you're going to have to just start using it a lot.  There is barrier of entry, with a pot of gold on the other side of the mountain.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Nice! The most accurate definition of Regex ;)

Comment: By the time I'm proficient as you I'll likely have the same rep as you do now and you double :D

Comment: Maybe...but there is a phenomenon/problem on the site, with major contributors quitting around 200K.  Once you get the second T-shirt, I guess what is the point of continuing :P

Comment: Although I'm unsure if this is faster than the split method for smething as structured as this ouput. Although regex offers more diversity

Comment: Wait there's T-Shirts?! Where's mine?

Comment: Can I obtain the result without the apostrophies(') on the values and get the result as a list of lists?

Comment: I don't see any apostrophes in your data.